# Increase in spams through website contact forms after change of server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, web-server, spam, web-hosting

I recently moved my website from Hostgator to an Amazon Web Services' EC2 instance. From a few days later people/bot started posting spam messages in the forms that are on the website.
Is there anything technical that may have triggered this? Is there anything that a system admin can do?

(The messages are being posted through the forms, they are not being sent using any API or by hacking into the system)

Comment: Some Bots just try every form they see, and they might have tried yours now because the domain happened to appear in public listings of active domains. E.g. the provider change has likely (re-)added your name in certificate logs. Not much you can do, other than making your form slightly less usable for bots and very much less usable for humans.

Comment: Set up CloudFlare for your website, ensure your security group only lets CloudFlare IPs and your public IP access your server.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your site's setup you could look into anti-spam tactics for your online form.  For example, Wordpress has plugins like Titan and Akismet which add anti-spam techniques like RE-Captcha and IP blocking, etc.

I can't speak to other "content management systems" or to your site exactly because I don't know its architecture but bots are ALWAYS active and building on what @anx said, something changed in how/where your site is being hosted and probably got moved to the top of a record or log of activity which caught the attention of some bots.